# Java: Comparing two collections for new or updated objects

Tags: java, performance, collections, comparison, java-7

I have two Collections or Arraylists of possibly unequal sizes that will need to be compared. One Collection is a newly downloaded Collection of objects from a REST payload. Another is a Collection from a local repository of Collection of objects. Neither of the Collections will have duplicate objects.

The idea is to find the new objects which doesn't exist in the local repository or objects which have been updated in the downloaded collection from the existing objects in the local repository. Thereby, the class will eventually have two methods to return a Collection of new objects and updated objects

Signature of an object consists of:

```
membershipObject:
                id
                start_date
                end_date
                uniqueId
```

`id` and `uniqueId` are unique in the collection that makes it ideal to compare them. `start_date` wouldn't usually change, but `end_date` can be null or have a datetime object. I have a support method to find if an Object is "active" or "inactive" depending on whether `end_date` is `null` or not.

And object is considered updated if the `end_date` has changed since my last download.

Eg:

```
downloadedCollection
    0:
      id: 1
      start_date: 2017-05-01 00:00:00
      end_date: null
      uniqueId: <unique-string-abc>
    1:
      id: 2
      start_date: 2017-04-01 00:00:00
      end_date: 2017-05-02 00:00:00
      uniqueId: <unique-string-cde>
    2:
      id: 3
      start_date: 2017-05-01 10:00:00
      end_date: null
      uniqueId: <unique-string-def>

localCollection
    0:
      id: 1
      start_date: 2017-05-01 00:00:00
      end_date: null
      uniqueId: <unique-string-abc>
    1:
      id: 2
      start_date: 2017-04-01 00:00:00
      end_date: null
      uniqueId: <unique-string-cde>
```

In the above example, `id 2` has been updated and `id 3` is new from the `downloadedCollection`.

What is the ideal Java way to compare these two collections considering the complexity of the operation? Java SDK 7.

Comment: Generally you don't try to compare the data to determine what has changed.  Instead, you set a "dirty" flag when you change anything to let any managing system know what to look at.

Comment: If you need to perform the operation as described, then you could implement a decent `hashCode()` method for the member objects, and a corresponding `equals()` method.  Then create a `HashSet` containing the elements of the newly-downloaded list, then `removeAll()` the elements of the reference list.  Whichever elements remain are new or different from the reference list, in the sense defined by the members' `equals()` methods.

Comment: @azurefrog Since this is being downloaded from a REST service, it cannot really be expected for the service to know what is dirty on the client.  Assuming the client actually needs to know what changed (instead of just simply using the latest data from the service), JohnBollinger's solution is quite good.

Comment: @JohnBollinger your solution works. I am able to separate the new/updated member objects. After calling `removeAll()`, in case I need to filter the remainder member objects into two separate sets, the solution I got currently is to iterate over the localCollection and the `HashSet`. I am checking for the unique id in the localCollection and adding to the updatedMemberSet and removing from the HashSet. I end up with two sets, one with new members and other with updated members.

Arguably, is there a better way to do this?

Answer (score 0):

Have an hash table maintain the id(key) and expiry info(value) available @ local. Whenever you receive new valves loop through them and update ur repository and hash table. This will run **O(n),** where n is the noof items in the new list.